# PowerShell get newest occurrence

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a folder that contains log files - simple text files, one per machine per month. I am able to list the files. How to get only the latest file per machine?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\Somefolder\subfolder\Logs' |
    Sort-Object lastwritetime |
    Select Name,LastWriteTime | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {$_.Name = ($_.Name).Substring(0,15) ;$_} |
    Format-Table Name,LastWriteTime
```

Comment: marc, thanks for the formatting help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\Somefolder\subfolder\Logs' |
    Sort-Object lastwritetime |
    Select @{Label='ComputerName';Expression={$_.Name.Substring(0,15)}}, Name, LastWriteTime | 
    Group-Object -Property ComputerName | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $LastItem = $_.Group[-1]
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'=$LastItem.ComputerName
            'FileName'=$LastItem.Name
            'LastWriteTime'=$LastItem.LastWriteTime
        }
    } | Format-Table ComputerName,LastWriteTime
```

Comment: That was great.  thanks.  Now i am trying to figure out how to eliminate or include subfolders and  to add a tab between columns in the result set.